Synchronous integration vs asynchronous integration in simulations with complex problems
Lets say i want to create a detailed simulation of a complex system. For instance a drone.
This simulation will have to contain a few models, each one with it's own requirements, for instance

A 6Dof flight mechanics model
An onboard autopilot
Actuators
Engine
others...

A typical way of setting up such a simulation would be to concatenate all models into a single "step" function. Every model's state variable would be added to a list and then use something like a Runge-Kutta integration scheme, which would call the step function, compute the next states which would keep the simulation going.
This is desirable as it does not -- (assuming no design error, like algebraic loops and such) --   introduce any latency between the models calls, which would create inconsistencies during the integration process.
However this method (which is the only one i have experience with) has a few drawbacks:

You can only use one single integration scheme and time step for the whole model or...
... if you want to mix schemes and/or time steps, you can create a "subsystem" but this subsystem's time step has to be a multiple of it's main system so for instance, if you mix many discrete models (for instance a gps, IMU and autopilot), each with a different frequency, you end up needing a very small timestep
Mixing some integration schemes, such as Verlet with something such as RK4 without introducing errors becomes a pain.

For context I am facing a problem where i want to simulate a complex system in which most of my models can be integrated with a RK4 algorithm. However for some of them, i would like to try a more specific integration scheme (namely a symplectic integrator and an implict scheme)
Hence my questions:

Is it reasonable to run different schemes in "parallel", while interpolating outputs when possible?

example:

Model A is integrated with a leapfrog scheme and uses Model B's outputs. Time step : 3
Model B is integrated with an RK4 scheme and uses Model A's outputs. Time step : 2

T = 0: Model A computes velocity at T = 1.5 and position at T = 3.0, using the output of model B for it's acceleration.
T = 2 : Model B computes its coefficients (k1, k2, k3, and k4) at Times = (2, 3, 3, 4).
T = 3 : Model A
T = 4 : Model B
T = 6 : Model A and Model B
etc...

If the latter example does make sens, i guess it would be detrimental to any Runge-Kutta's stability and precision (except Euler) However:

Would it also compromise it's convergence? (would be a bummer)
If it does not compromise convergence, how much error would be introduced into the system?


Is there already some existing litterature on such a way to solve complex dynamical systems or some software that already does it? (from what i saw, simulink does use the "synchronous" method)



Unless you have to write something in a very low-level computing environment, I would highly suggest using existing packages that include features like error estimators, adaptive stepping, more schemes, etc. than writing your own integration scheme. Chances are that if you can interface your system with one of these packages, it will perform better than combining simple schemes you happen to know

I would advise checking out splitting schemes (which can be seen as decoupling schemes), but also co-simulation and multirate schemes. These methods all require some kind of synchronicity, since all the subsolvers have to meet at specific coupling time points, but they can perform as many substeps as they desire, with any numerical scheme under the hood.

@whpowell96, I get your point, however, i'd like to do this myself as i have some specific needs that i must address and from what i've seen, there is no library that does what i want. (apart from simulink, but i dont own a licence and dont plan on using matlab any time soon)

@Laurent90 interesting, thanks!
